# hadoop mapreduce two sorts

Tags: sorting, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop mapreduce. I went through some of the tutorials and noticed that the output of the mapper is sorted while in the reducer side, we also have a shuffle & sort phase.

So why do we have two sorts there? What are the purposes of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mapper : It arranges the input data from a source into key value pairs for further processing.

Reducer: Aggregation Logic is written here.

Role of Shuffler is shuffle and sort and it passes output from mapper to reducer.This is done internally by MR framework.But,we can implement our own custom shuffler in using MR Api and Java.

Refer this example of WordCount:

http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.in/2011/04/word-count-hadoop-map-reduce-example.html
Refer this also.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks @TKHN for your answer. I'm wondering that sorting the output of mapper helps emit key-value pairs to the right reducer while reducer sorts the key-value pairs to group them faster, right?